# how to install module sqlite3 on node if error

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I try to install module sqlite? but there is an error, what to do:

`$ npm install sqlite3
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported`

> sqlite3@5.0.0 install D:\CODE\21_data\node_modules\sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

Node.js is only supported on Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, or higher.
Setting the NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK environment variable to 1 skips this
check, but Node.js might not execute correctly. Any issues encountered on
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\CODE\21_data\package.json'
npm WARN 21_data No description
npm WARN 21_data No repository field.
npm WARN 21_data No README data
npm WARN 21_data No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 216
npm ERR! sqlite3@5.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 216
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@5.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: i use windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Problems solved:
1.npm cache clean --force
2.delete node_modules folder
3.delete package-lock.json file
4.npm install